# Ekiga doesnt make calls, using Asterisk server on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: asterisk, ekiga

I have an Asterisk server running Ubuntu 16.04 on VBOX on my local host. Also have two Ekiga clients: one on a different Ubuntu machine (on VBOX) and one on my local host (windows 10).

I just finished configuring Asterisk and at least thought I did well, but when I'm trying to make calls between the two Ekiga Clients it doesn't make them.

```
Error: "Call from guy to extension '100' has rejected because Extension not found"
```

altough I DID configured that extension as you can see in the photo: when I run `dialplan show 100@phones` it shows me the dial plan.

no communication problem between peers and server as server NOTICED when i Started ekiga clients. also when i command

> 'sip show peers'

I can see the two peers available

`extension.conf`:

```
[phones]
exten => 100,1,NoOp(print something)
exten => 100,2,Dial(SIP/Asterisk)
exten => 100,3,Hangup
```

Maybe the operation number 2 isn't alright because I don't have a SIP provider (internal network)?

Please check the following photo to see that Asterisk does acknowledge the clients: [on asterisk cli](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E005T.png)

Comment: Don't provide information as image which can be text.